# Python: updating queue every seconds and iterating the same in another method

Tags: python, queue

I have a python GUI application. I have a method that generates a random number every second (i call it queueMsg). If the queueMsg value is a particular value, (say 1), there is another variable called checkMsg will become 5. in all other conditions checkMsg = 0. 
I am using this Queue data in another method to assign this values to 2 variables and do some operations. How do I assign these data to variables. Do I need to clear data in the queue after using it or new data will erase the old data in the queue? any suggestions please

```
def workerThread(self):
        while self.running:
            time.sleep(1)          
            queueMsg = random.randint(0,9)
            checkMsg=0
            if (queueMsg==1):
                checkMsg= 1
            self.queue.put(queueMsg,checkMsg)   #is this right way to add data

def processData(self):
        while self.queue.qsize():
            try:
                msg1 = self.queue.get(0) 
                msg2 = self.queue.get(1)
#this is not the right way to iterate q data?
# it also takes extra time to do it. this was freezing the program              
                print (msg1)
                print (msg2)   

# what i want is assign queue data to two variables msg1 and msg2    
            except queue.Empty:
                pass
```

Comment: Sounds like you need: `msg1,msg2 = self.queue.get()`

Comment: @quamrana  that is what I want. but it doesn't work
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object

Comment: Ok, you also need `self.queue.put( (queueMsg,checkMsg) )`. Note how the extra brackets creates a `tuple` which my first comment unpacks. You need to read the documentation on `get()` and `put()`.

Comment: It works. Thanks. I am reading the documentation right now :)

Comment: @quamrana Could you please have a look at this link -->
https://stackoverflow.com/q/56937694/11372345